# With or without squeeze theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I am doing a proof involving finding the sum of a series $\sum_{x\geq1} \frac{x}{2^x} - \frac{x+1}{2^{x+1}}$ and I need to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x+1}{2^x}$ converges to $0$ without using L'Hopital's theorem.

My attempt:

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x+1}{2^x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{2^x} + \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{2^x}$

We then get that $2^x > x^2 \implies \frac{x}{2^x} < \frac{x}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x}$ and also, $2^x > x \implies \frac{1}{2^x} < \frac{1}{x}$ for sufficiently large $x$. We have that

$$0 \leq \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{2^x} \leq \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$$

$$0 \leq \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{2^x} \leq \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$$

(Notice the change from $<$ to $\leq$ above. Is that allowed? Also, the series starts at $1$, not $0$.)

Using squeeze theorem, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x+1}{2^x} = 0$.

Is this correct? Notice my bracketed comment. Any assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in the context of a series, *$x$ is natural*.

So, you can apply the binomial formula to $2^x = (1+1)^x=\sum_{n=0}^x\binom xn$:

$$0\leq \frac{x}{2^x} = \frac{x}{(1+1)^x} \stackrel{x\geq 2}{\leq} \frac{x}{\binom x2} = \frac 2{x-1}\stackrel{x\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Similarly for the case $\frac 1{2^x}$.

Comment: So is my method wrong then? After all, $2^x > x^2 > \frac{x^2 - x}{2} = \frac{x(x-1)}{2} = x C 2$

Comment: @Kraftsman No. Your method is ok. But you use inequalities which you may also need to show first before using them. That's why I showed you a way without assuming any other inequality.